# Making Python script tool run immediately upon opening?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-script-tool

I have an ArcGIS 10.1 script tool that creates an ArcSDE connection folder and copies data from the server to a new folder on the users computer. The tool has no parameters runs fine but when you open the tool it gives the default "this tool has no parameters" interface the user then presses ok and the tool runs. Is there anyway(perhaps with toolvalidator) to just run the script when the tool is opened without this pop-up?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you [add a geoprocessing tool to a toolbar](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002400000005000000) it will run immediately upon clicking it, provided it has no parameters:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: +1, I did not know this.

Comment: I believe this was added at 10.0: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00qp0000000q000000.htm

Comment: Awesome I had no idea they added that.